# How to preserve SSH_CLIENT in `sudo su -`

Tags: sudo, su

I want to log commands executed by a user, part of that log is the originating IP address which is read from `SSH_CLIENT`.

While it is possible to use `env_keep += "SSH_CLIENT"` in `/etc/sudoers` to make this environment variable stick across `sudo`. Most common way to use `sudo` it to create a new login shell, using `sudo su -`.

New login shell, when created this way, does not preserve any of the environment variables that sudo preserves.

Is there some way to still recognize the originating IP address for a user who logs in and goes into root shell using `sudo su -`?

Comment: looks like you answered your own question. or, `sudo -E su -`.

Comment: I am not asking how to do it when I run the command. The question is about how to do it when other people don't follow the proper flags and just punch in the command: sudo su -

Comment: I stumbled upon this question and @strobelight comment, they are useful to me. Note: if *sudo -E su* doesn't preserve the variable, try with *sudo -i* or *sudo -E bash*